# Entity Framework 6.3 as a Service and .Net Core 3

Tags: .net, wcf, asp.net-core-3.0

I have an existing WCF service that uses an .edmx model.  I have a second service that has a method to call a stored procedure.  I have updated the services to Entity Framework 6.3.  Now I am trying to call them using a .NET Core 3 application.  So far, I am only able to add a reference to the service that has methods that call stored procedures.

Question 1:  Is it possible to create a reference to the service using the .edmx model?  So far, I cannot even get this far, much less use the service.

Question 2:  The service which has methods now has two methods for each one created.  For example, I have a method called "CallStoredProcedure", the service has two methods:  CallStoredProcedureRequest and CallStoredProcedureResponse.  How do I use these methods?  Current code (4.7.2) allows me to call the original method with no problems.

Comment: write a small worker service.

Comment: My sample couldn't be any smaller.  I'm confused by the method being converted to "Request" and "Response".  I have no idea how to use these.

Comment: small worker service doesn't have to be smaller, write it and set the interval to execute whatever methods you have.